# Pythonic way to check if something exists?

Tags: python, if-statement

This is pretty basic but I was coding and started wondering if there was a pythonic way to check if something does not exist.  Here's how I do it if its true:

```
var = 1
if var:
    print 'it exists'
```

but when I check if something does not exist, I often do something like this:

```
var = 2
if var:
    print 'it exists'
else:
    print 'nope it does not'
```

Seems like a waste if all I care about is knIs there a way to check if something does not exist without the else?

Comment: There's always ternary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator :)  ... thought it might not be the most Pythonic way to write it out.

Comment: If `var` doesn't actually **exist**, then you are going to get an exception raised when you try to use it. That is outside of what `if`/`else` can handle. `if var` **assumes** that `var` exists, and **tests** if it is "true-ish" (becomes True rather than False if converted to boolean).

Comment: You are not checking the existence of a variable, but checking if it's value is `True`as a boolean context.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

LBYL style, "look before you leap":

```
var_exists = 'var' in locals() or 'var' in globals()
```

EAFP style, "easier to ask forgiveness than permission":

```
try:
    var
except NameError:
    var_exists = False
else:
    var_exists = True
```

Prefer the second style (EAFP) when coding in Python, because it is generally more reliable.

Comment: Test if var does not exist: 'var' not in locals() and 'var' not in globals()

Answer (score 44):

I think you have to be careful with your terminology, whether something *exists* and something evaluates to *False* are two different things. Assuming you want the latter, you can simply do:

```
if not var:
   print 'var is False'
```

For the former, it would be the less elegant:

```
try:
   var
except NameError:
   print 'var not defined'
```

I am going to take a leap and venture, however, that whatever is making you want to check whether a variable is defined can probably be solved in a more elegant manner.

Comment: sorry didn't mean false. meant if it does not exist.  I use it more often in sql queries(I wrap an if statement in a select query and if no result comes back then I do some work), so not false looking for not existing.

Comment: well `config = config()` and then `if not config:` gives me "local variable config referenced before assigment" :)

Answer (score 7):

If this is a dictionary, you can have

```
mydict['ggg'] = ''   // doesn't matter if it is empty value or not.
if mydict.has_key('ggg'):
   print "OH GEESH"
```

However, `has_key()` is completely removed from Python 3.x, therefore, the Python way is to use `in`

```
'ggg' in mydict     # this is it!
# True if it exists
# False if it doesn't
```

You can use `in` for tuple, list, and set as well.

---

Of course, if the variable hasn't been defined, you will have to raise an exception silently (just raise any exception... let it pass), if exception is not what you want to see (which is useful for many applications, you just need to log the exception.)

---

It is always safe to define a variable before you use it (you will run into "assignment before local reference" which means " var is not in the scope " in plain English). If you do something with query, the chance is, you will want to have a dictionary, and checking whether a key exists or not, use `in` .

Comment: Simplest of all the solutions

Comment: This doesn't work for a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

```
if not var:
    #Var is None/False/0/

if var:
    #Var is other then 'None/False/0'
```

in Python if varibale is having any value from None/False/0 then `If var` condition will fail...

and for other objects it will call `__nonzero__` pythonic method which may return `True` or `False` depending on its functionality.

Comment: This will not handle the case where the variable was never defined, which is OP's question.

Answer (score 6):

To check if a var has been defined:

```
var = 2

try: 
    var
except NameError:
    print("No var")
```

To check if it is None/False

```
if var is None
```

...or

```
if not var
```

Answer (score 3):

What about the negation?

```
if not var:
    print 'nope it does not'
```

Though this is to see if the var is false / none and would blow up if var is not defined.

To see if var is defined:

```
try:
    var
except NameError:
    print 'not defined'
```