# function_exists in PHP for python3

Tags: python

Is there something like [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) in PHP for Python3? I am implementing something that allows users (through some web UI) to define simple rules in JSON as follows (in some weird lisp-like structure):

```
["_and", ["_tautology"], ["tautology"]]
```

and would like to turn that into a python statement, for instance these functions

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

def _and(*args):
    return lambda context: reduce(operator.and, [arg(context) for arg in args], True)

def _tautology(*_):
    return lambda *__: True
```

by turning that original JSON rule into

```
_and(_tautology(), _tautology())
```

Just out of curiousity, is `ast` made for this kind of task? I did this once before but I am looking for something that is scalable. Because what I did before this was practically maintaining a dictionary like follows

```
mapping = {'_and': _and}
```

and the list would keep growing, and that results in more code typed to describe what the string value means, instead of implementing them. Or I should have used another rule engine? Because one of the rule would look like

```
["_and", ["_equals", "fieldA", "some_value"],
         ["_equals", "fieldB", "some_other_value"]]
```

Assuming `_equals` is

```
def _equals(field_name, value):
    return lambda context: context[field_name] == value
```

so that the rule is expanded to

```
_and(_equals('fieldA', 'some_value'),
     _equals('fieldB', 'some_other_value'))
```

**TL;DR**

*Main Question:* is there something like `function_exists` for Python3, is `ast` suitable for this?
*Secondary Question:* should I use some sort of rule engine instead?

**Regarding the duplicate question report** No, I am not checking if a variable exists. I want to know if there is a function that has the same name, as a string value. For example, if I have a string `'_and'` I want to know if there is a function named `_and`, not trying to figure out whether this identifier `_and` is actually a function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-python

Comment: For this kind of task you should create a decorator that registers your functions automatically to the mapping based on name. Makes life a lot easier.

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390126/pythonic-way-to-check-if-something-exists to check "Is `foobar` defined?" and then  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18704793/1191425 to determine "Is `foobar` a function?"

Comment: @ija I don't understand lol, mind to elaborate how it is done?

Comment: @li-aung yip not applicable, I need to find out whether there is a function which has the same name as the string value, there is no variable pointing to any function

Comment: @Jeffrey04 `def _and(...): ...` will actually also create a variable `_and` that references the function `<function _and ...>`. So in a way those other linked questions do answer part of your own post. There's no separate function namespace ala some Lisps in python.

Comment: i know the identifier `_and` points to the function, but I am looking for something more like `function_exists` in PHP, where the parameter is actually a string, to find if the string value matches any function that has the same name.

Comment: @Jeffrey04 Python is not PHP. By any function do you mean that you wish to expose builtins and the like to your site users (a bad idea)?

Comment: actually there's another step i need to do before doing the mapping check, for example, '_and' is going to be expanded to something like 'rules.boolean._and' and then I go look for the function. I just didn't include it in the original question for clarity purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Morton pointed out, you could use `globals()` and `locals()` to fetch a variable using a string containing the name.

```
In [32]: a = 1

In [33]: def b():
    c = 2
    print(globals()['a'])
    print(globals()['b'])
    print(locals()['c'])
   ....:     

In [34]: b()
1
<function b at 0x7f425cae3ae8>
2
```

But! For your task I would recommend using a decorator that registers your functions to a mapping automatically.

```
_mapping = {}


def register(f):
    _mapping[f.__name__] = f
    return f


@register
def _and(*args):
    return lambda context: reduce(operator.and_,
                                  [arg(context) for arg in args], True)

@register
def _tautology(*_):
    return lambda *_: True
```

and so your `function_exists` would be just

```
_mapping[key]
```

AST is suitable for inspecting syntax trees generated from parsed python source, modifying existing syntax trees and generating new ones and transpiling to python from a different language by generating syntax trees from it (to name a few uses). So in a way yes, you could generate AST from your JSON and compile that. I believe that is actually what [Hy](http://docs.hylang.org/en/latest/) does, though not from JSON, but full blown lisp syntax.

Comment: Oooo, now I understand